# how to hide group menu item and display when it clickable

Tags: android

This is my menu i want to hide the group of club menu item and when it clickable i need to show it how ......... don't know how to code so can you explain me how to code.. i used visibility option in item attribute but it will no display at run time

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/zonevi"
        android:title="Rotaract Club Of "
        android:icon="@drawable/zonevi">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/club1"
                android:title="Budhanilkantha"
                android:icon="@drawable/zonevi"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/club2"
                android:title="Dillibazar Kathmandu"
                android:icon="@drawable/zonevi"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/club3"
                android:title="Gongabu"
                android:icon="@drawable/zonevi"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/club4"
                android:title="Kantipur"
                android:icon="@drawable/zonevi"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/club5"
                android:title="Kathmandu Metro"
                android:icon="@drawable/zonevi"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/club6"
                android:title="Kathmandu North East"
                android:icon="@drawable/zonevi"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/club7"
                android:title="Kanthmandu Sunrise"
                android:icon="@drawable/zonevi"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/club8"
                android:title="Kathmandu Youth North East"
                android:icon="@drawable/zonevi"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/club9"
                android:title="Pashupati-Kathmandu"
                android:icon="@drawable/zonevi"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/club10"
                android:title="Rajdhan"
                android:icon="@drawable/zonevi"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/club11"
                android:title="Swoyambhu"
                android:icon="@drawable/zonevi"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/club12"
                android:title="Thames International College"
                android:icon="@drawable/zonevi"/>
        </menu>

    </item>
```

Comment: try this, I haven't try this but it may help menuItemId.setVisibility(View.GONE); when menu item not needed and menuItemId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); when Needed

Comment: where are you using this menu , in navigation drawer or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Add an atribute `android:visibility="gone"` to your XML like:

```
        <item
        android:id="@+id/zonevi"
        android:title="Rotaract Club Of "
        android:icon="@drawable/zonevi"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <menu>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/club1"
        android:title="Budhanilkantha"
        android:icon="@drawable/zonevi"/>
    ....................................
        </menu>

    </item>
```

And then when your element is clickable use methods:

```
YourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

or

```
YourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```